# Generate ZIP archive on the fly with files from Amazon S3 using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, zip

I have Rails 4 application that implements photogallary fucntionality: users have some kind of albums with photos, files are stored at Amazon S3 bucket. Some users want to be able to download album photos as zip archive.

Is it possible to generate zip archive on the fly without downloading all files from S3 to temporary directory and zipping them there?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this?